# GTK3.0+ App UI freeze problems. Threading problems

Tags: c, multithreading, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I am making a little project in C and using GTK for UI. I have a problem with freezes and exceptions, which as I assume are triggered by the way my app uses threads. 
I needed to stop the app (the functions like playersTurn(), leftBotsTurn()), in order to wait for user input(used while(var); loops, var is set to false after the user clicks any button.) For this purposes I started using threads, because if you don't let the window function finish it won't draw the window.

So there are few functions:

**Main**:

```
int main (int    argc,  char **argv){
  openMenu(argc, argv);
  return 0;}
```

**openMenu**

```
static void openMenu(int argc, char *argv[]){
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("menu_window_glade.glade");
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu_window"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();
}
```

**newGame**

```
void newGame(){

    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;
    widgetsPtrs *widgets = (widgetsPtrs *) malloc(sizeof(widgetsPtrs));

    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("game_glade.glade");
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "game_glade_window"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);


    /* Getting PlayersHand, AttackingRow, DefendingRow,TrumpImage pointers.  */
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){    
        //The code is hidden, but all it does is uses gtk_builder_get_object and saves pointers
        //in "widgets"        
}

     //g_mutex_init(myMutex); Tried to use mutex, but I couldn't find any example of g_mutex. 

    GThread *thread;
    thread = g_thread_new("gameLoop", gameLoop, widgets);
    }
```

**Game loop**

```
    void *gameLoop(void *value){

    widgetsPtrs *widgets = (widgetsPtrs *)value;
    cardsOnTheTable = malloc(sizeof(card));
    cardsOnTheTable->next = NULL;

    shuffleTheDeck();//allocates a card for the Deck. Shuffles it, makes a SLL out of it.

    player = malloc(sizeof(card));
    leftBot = malloc(sizeof(card));
    rightBot = malloc(sizeof(card));
    player->next = NULL;
    leftBot->next = NULL;
    rightBot->next = NULL;

    deal(player);
    deal(leftBot);
    deal(rightBot);
    printPlayersCards(player, leftBot, rightBot);

    //g_mutex_lock(myMutex);
    //Setting trump image.
    card *tmpTrumpCard = getTheLastCard(Deck);
    setCardImage(tmpTrumpCard, GTK_IMAGE(widgets->w_trumpImagePtr));
    //g_mutex_lock(myMutex);

    int a = firstTurnCheck();
    int turnResult = 0;
    while((Deck->next != NULL) || ((player->next != NULL) && ((leftBot->next != NULL) || (rightBot->next != NULL)) ) ){
        //g_mutex_lock(myMutex);
        showPlayerCards(widgets);
        sleep(1);
        if((a % 3) == 0){
            puts("PlayersTurn. //GameLoop");
            turnResult = playersTurn(widgets);
            if(turnResult == 1){
                a = 1;
            }else{
                a = 2;
            }
        }else if((a % 3) == 1){
            puts("LeftbotsTurn. //GameLoop");
            turnResult = leftBotsTurn(widgets);
            if(turnResult == 1){
                a = 2;
            }else{
                a = 0;
            }
        }else if((a%3) == 2){
            puts("RightbotsTurn. //GameLoop");
            turnResult = rightBotsTurn(widgets);
            if(turnResult == 1){
                a = 0;
            }else{
                a = 1;
            }
        }
        hidePlayerCards(widgets);
        deal(player);
        deal(leftBot);
        deal(rightBot);
        clearTheTable(widgets);
        printPlayersCards(player, leftBot, rightBot);
        cardsOnTheTable->next = NULL;
        //g_mutex_unlock(myMutex);
        sleep(1);
    }


    // while((Deck->next != NULL) || (player->next != NULL && leftBot->next != NULL) || (player->next != NULL && rightBot->next != NULL)){
    //     gtk_widget_set_sensitive((widgets->w_buttons[2]), true);
    //     if(a == 0){

    //     }else if(a == 1){

    //     }else if(a == 2){

    //     }
    // }

    if(player->next == NULL){
        puts("You won!");
    }else{
        puts("Jokes on you. ");
    }
    //pthread_exit(NULL);
    free(player);
    free(leftBot);
    free(rightBot);
    free(Deck);
    free(widgets);
    free(cardsOnTheTable);
    return NULL;}
```

**Errors**

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
main: ../../src/xcb_io.c:165: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue??

Comment: I am not sure I understand the _italicized_ text in your problem description at top.  Are you quoting someone, or just emphasizing what you thought you needed to do?  i.e. I would thing one would never need to, or want to _freeze the app_ for any reason.  The UI is typically launched, and running in the initial program thread, uses event handler functions (callbacks) to handle button clicks etc.  Additional threads would be launched to handle any _blocking_ event handling that one of the button clicks would result in, so the user could, for example click an abort button.

Comment: Hello again @ryyker. You were the one who advised me using threads to take care of this problem. By "freezing" app I mean making the app wait for user to press a button.

Comment: You cannot use GTK from a thread, you have to safely return data to the main thread, often using `g_idle_add()`

Comment: @TingPing Thanks a lot. May I ask you for an example? Or where would you put it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialise support for concurrent threads 
call XInitThreads(); before gtk_init();

you can only update the gui from the main thread. To invoke changes from a different thread you have to call g_idle_add().

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int counter = 0;

void idleLoop(gpointer data) {
  char *yolo = g_strdup_printf("counting ... %d", counter);
  gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(data), yolo);
  g_free(yolo);
}

void *gameLoop(gpointer data) {

  printf("starting loop \n");
  while (1) {
    counter++;
    /*
    #IMPO# putting the ui update command here wont work
      char *yolo = g_strdup_printf("counting ... %d", counter);
       gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(data), yolo);
      g_free(yolo);
    */
    g_usleep(5000);
    g_idle_add(idleLoop, data);
  }

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(win), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(win), FALSE);
  GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(
      "<big>This is a long text that might need to be wrapped</big>");
  gtk_label_set_use_markup(GTK_LABEL(label), TRUE);
  g_object_set(label, "margin", 20, NULL);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win), label);

  gtk_label_set_line_wrap(GTK_LABEL(label), TRUE);
  gtk_label_set_max_width_chars(GTK_LABEL(label), 30);
  g_signal_connect(GTK_WIDGET(win), "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(win));

  g_thread_new("gameLoop", gameLoop, label);

  gtk_main();
}
```

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add

this will give you a better undestaring of main loop (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html)